# Split array into div

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have this array :

```
$result = array('description1', 'description2', 'description3', 'description4', 'description5'
```

I want to split this array into divs like this :

- $result[0] - $result[1] => put these into a div
- $result[2] - $result[3] => put these into a div
- $result[4]   => put this into a div

My entire structure

```
$content = get_the_content();
                $description = array();
                $j=0;  


                    if (preg_match_all('/<div id="description" class="description">([^<]*)<\/div>/', $content, $match)) {


                        for( $i = 0; $i < count($match[0]); $i = $i+1 ) {

                            $description[] = $match[0][$i];

                        }

                    }       

                    $attachments =& get_children($args);    
                    $arrayMatches = array();

                        if ($attachments) {
                            foreach(array_chunk($attachments, 2) as $img) {
                                echo '<div class="two_cols">';
                                foreach($img as $attachment) {
                                    foreach($attachment as $attachment_key => $attachment_value) {
                                        $imageID = $attachment->ID;
                                        $imageTitle = $attachment->post_title;
                                        $imagearray = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_value, $size, false);
                                        $imageAlt = get_post_meta($imageID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                                        $imageURI = $imagearray[0]; // 0 is the URI
                                        $imageWidth = $imagearray[1]; // 1 is the width
                                        $imageHeight = $imagearray[2]; // 2 is the height
                                ?>

                                <div class="col_1_2">

                                        <!-- A picure Here -->
                                        <?php $arrayMatches[] = $match[0][$j]; ?>

                                </div>


                            <?php

                            break;

                        }

                        $j++;

                    }

                        $arrayMatches = array_chunk($arrayMatches, 2);
                        echo "<div>";
                         foreach($arrayMatches as $v) {
                            echo implode($v);
                        }
                        echo "</div>";

                echo '</div>';

            }       

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I try this `$result = array();
       foreach(array_chunk($arrayMatches,2) as $k => $desc) {
foreach($desc as $item) {
  $result[] = $item;
}
}
print_r($result);`

Comment: ^ Add this to your question and show your effort!

Comment: Can you use javascript to do it ?

Comment: You should make clear with your question how it differs from existing material (that works best by providing reference to existing material and then explaining at which level it's not suitable in your case) otherwise it might tend to be too broad and unclear what exactly you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Just chunk your array with [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). And then you can simply loop through your array, output it into a div and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the elements.

```
<?php

    $result = array('description1', 'description2', 'description3', 'description4', 'description5');
    $result = array_chunk($result, 2);

    foreach($result as $v) {
        echo "<div>" . implode(" ", $v) . "</div>";
    }

?>
```

output:

```
<div>description1 description2</div>
<div>description3 description4</div>
<div>description5</div>
```

**EDIT:**

As from your updated array structure just grab all values first like this:

```
$result = [];
$arr = array(['description1'], ['description2'], 'description3', 'description4', 'description5');  //example
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k)use(&$result){
    $result[] = $v;
});
$result = array_chunk($result, 2);
```

Comment: It almost works but at the beginning of the second and third div, the string 'Array' appear. `<div>Array description3 description4</div> <div>Array Array description5</div>`

Comment: @user3653409 Then I think you don't show us your real array structure! Please make sure you show us your **real** and **full** array + how the expected output should look like

Comment: @user3653409 Please add the **exact** output of: `print_r($result);` which you get. Also if you try my code make sure you have error reporting turned on at the top of your file(s):  `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` And tell us if you get any

Comment: The exact output : `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => description1 [1] => Description2) [1] => Description3) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
Description4) ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>Description5) ) `

Comment: @user3653409 updated my answer. Now it should work all fine! (You also might want to update your question with the real array structure)

Comment: @user3653409 So where are we now with this question?

Comment: I does not work :/ It actually appears like this http://imgur.com/wap6hJ5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76899/discussion-between-user3653409-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just echo them in divs:

```
<div>
    <?php echo $result[0] . "-" . $result[1]; ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $result[2] . "-" . $result[3]; ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $result[4]; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to do it in a loop

Comment: For the above mentioned scenario, is this the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to control whether you are in the last 2 positions or not.

```
echo '<div>';

for ($i=0;$i<count($result);$i=$i+2) {
    if ($i+1 >= count($result)) {
        echo $result[$i];
    } else {
        echo $result[$i].$result[$i+1];
        echo '</div><div>';
    }
}

echo '</div>;
```