# how to make a set of each 2 values in a loop in php

Tags: php, loops

```
The loop returns like this
value 1
value 2
value 3
value 4
value 5
value 6
value 7
value 8
value 9
value 10


The following should be my output

------------------------------
    value 1
1
    value 2
------------------------------
    value 3
2   
    value 4
-------------------------------
    value 5
3   
    value 6
-------------------------------
    value 7
4       
    value 8
-------------------------------
    value 9
5       
    value 10
--------------------------------
```

Can any one help I have searched lot more reference on internet.

Comment: what've your tryed?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: i am planning to create question paper auto generation application, so in that part b of a question paper has either or choice question like question no 1 (a)bla bla or (b)bla bla bla then question no 2 (a) bla bla bla or (b)bla bla bla like this

Comment: i got a loop of 10 questions i need to merge it in to either or choice question in to 5 sets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031267/split-array-into-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_chunk() like below:

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes","Opel");
echo "<pre>"; print_r(array_chunk($cars,2));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => BMW
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Toyota
            [1] => Honda
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mercedes
            [1] => Opel
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your array and take two like so:

```
$test = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i += 2) {
  $j = $i + 1;
  echo "$test[$i] \n"; 
  echo "$test[$j] \n";
}
```

Comment: Your ans is this 1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10